# Canvas fill/strokeText adds random marks to canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text, canvas

So I've been working on this canvas drawing app. One component of it allows you to add text to the canvas using the fill and stroke text methods.

Sometimes, upon adding the text, random markings, usually dots or lines, appear.

[image: First Example]

[image: Second Example]

Here is the code that adds it. It is in Angular.js.

```
  /* Accept */
  accept.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var lines = text.value.split('\n'); // Split based on line break
    // For each line break, draw the text
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
      // Calculate the next line
      var y = parseInt(coords.y) + (40*i); // Mostly arbitrary number, the font size is 37
      $scope.ctx.strokeText(lines[i], coords.x, y);
      $scope.ctx.fillStyle = $scope.canvas.modes.create.instruments.defaults.strokeStyle;
      $scope.ctx.fillText(lines[i], coords.x, y);
      $scope.ctx.fill();
      $scope.ctx.stroke();
    }
    // Make hitory
    $scope.makeHistory();
    // remove the text box
    $element.remove();
  }, false);
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Based on a comment suggestion here's some more info:

[image: Adding text.]

[image: Text added, with marking.]

Logged text output: `Such string. Many texts. Wow.`

Comment: Hard to say with the code provided. If it's unintentional it might be a left-over or wrongly parsed part of the string you seem to parse. What does the source string look like?

Comment: Understood, it's hard to decide on what code to show as I have no idea where this might be coming from. I'll edit the above and post some source strings.

Comment: you have junk in your array, which is caused by splitting a string by `\n` and that means that there is an "non-empty" last line in your text. Consider trimming it, or sanitizing in other way.

Comment: @c69 I thought that too, but logging the split would always return the appropriate amount of indexes. I'll add a trim and report my findings.

Comment: @Ken in that case, only step-by-step debugging can help. F8, F8, F8, ..

Comment: Thanks everyone. Will nail this down eventually.

Comment: First thing i would do would be to have a one-line version working first (no spliting, no for loop). And only after, write a multi-line version calling the one-line function for each line.